# Is there a difference between `[^\b]` and `.`?

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation

Is there a difference between `[^\b]` and `.`?

I was modifying some code created by someone else that included this no-word-boundary-character-class (`[^\b]`). and am not able to find a difference between that and wildcard `.` (this is in ruby).

My assumption was that `[^\b]+` when applied to the string `hello world` should match `hello` and stop before the space, (as that is where there is a word boundary.

My observation is that it seems to just match everything. [rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/b06M3OhelZ).

What should be happening here?

Comment: Any zero-width assertion loses its meaning inside a character class. See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/54MTLn). `[^\b]` matches any char but a backspace char.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `\B`? the opposite of `\b`

Comment: If you want `hello`, just use `[a-z]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[\b]` means backspace and `[^\b]` not a backspace

`\b` is not a character, it can't be included in a character class.

The negation of a word boundary is `\B`

Comment: Backspace? What do you mean?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: The character backspace, octal `010` or decimal `8`

Comment: I'll be damned, it does mean that. TIL